# Removing duplicate objects with Underscore for Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I have this kind of array:

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];
```

I'd like to filter it to have:

```
var bar = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }];
```

I tried using _.uniq, but I guess because `{ "a" : "1" }` is not equal to itself, it doesn't work. Is there any way to provide underscore uniq with an overriden equals function?

Comment: Please post your code as well

Comment: Do things like `{ "a" : "2" }` exist? If so is it the attribute or the value that makes it unique?

Comment: Yes I do have an attribute as key, I implemented the index someone showed me on another topic, but then I wanted to clean my code using some common libraries

Comment: Pleae change accepted answer.

Answer (score 233):

*.uniq/*.unique accepts a callback

```
var list = [{a:1,b:5},{a:1,c:5},{a:2},{a:3},{a:4},{a:3},{a:2}];

var uniqueList = _.uniq(list, function(item, key, a) { 
    return item.a;
});

// uniqueList = [Object {a=1, b=5}, Object {a=2}, Object {a=3}, Object {a=4}]
```

Notes:

1. Callback return value used for comparison
2. First comparison object with unique return value used as unique
3. [underscorejs.org](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#uniq) demonstrates no callback usage
4. [lodash.com](http://lodash.com/docs#uniq) shows usage

Another example : 
[using the callback to extract car makes, colors from a list](http://jsbin.com/evodub/13/edit)

Comment: `false` is not required for `_.uniq()`. Also in lodash you could have wrote it like this `_.uniq(a, 'a');`, since it'll pluck the property `a` on the objects.

Comment: The "'_.pluck' callback shorthand" only works if you pass a value for  isSorted (e.g. `_.uniq(a, false, 'a')`) I pinged github/bestiejs/lodash and they said the issue was fixed on edge. So if you're not using a function, make sure you have the latest. This may not be an issue for underscore.

Comment: Iterator doesn't sound like a good name, it's a hash like function that will be to determine identity of each object

Comment: Edited to use callback to be more consistent with lodash docs :)

Comment: You example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/evodub/13/edit) can have a update. (1) Makes : _(cars).uniq('make').map('make').valueOf() AND (2) Colors: _(cars).uniq('color').map('color').valueOf(). You can ripe off the color and make closures. (All that if you upgrade de lodash used)

Comment: Yes! I totally encourage you to post said update in an edit. :)

Comment: The issue with this, the iteratee only transforms each element to another value which will be checked for uniqueness. If you don't know (or don't want to know) the actual format of the objects, then you will need to stringify the objects. I recommend you look at [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17479527/1104107) which is more flexible and compares objects based on their properties.

Comment: No. Stringify won't solve that problem because stringify is non-deterministic, furthermore uniq uses a where style callback to compare two object with a deep comparison for equality. maybe it didn't work for some edge case, but for most situations this is totally sufficient.

Comment: how dooes one know order and no of parameters passed in callback function "function(item, key, a)" ?

Comment: The [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs) are pretty good with explanation of the callback. Most of the lodash functions use the same values for the callback. I remember *VIL* or `Value`, `Index`, `List`. With exceptions, like `reduce` which precedes that with `Result`.

Comment: what about little more complicated example: 
{day: 15, month: 8, year: 2017}
1
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}
2
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}
3
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}
4
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}
5
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}
6
:
{day: 14, month: 8, year: 2017}

Comment: What did you have in mind? Did you see the car make/color link. You can apply that code to dates as well. :) http://jsbin.com/evodub/13/edit?js,output

Answer (score 38):

If you're looking to remove duplicates based on an id you could do something like this:

```
var res = [
  {id: 1, content: 'heeey'},
  {id: 2, content: 'woah'}, 
  {id: 1, content:'foo'},
  {id: 1, content: 'heeey'},
];
var uniques = _.map(_.groupBy(res,function(doc){
  return doc.id;
}),function(grouped){
  return grouped[0];
});

//uniques
//[{id: 1, content: 'heeey'},{id: 2, content: 'woah'}]
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work when the unique identifier is a `Date`. However this does.

Answer (score 17):

Implementation of Shiplu's answer.

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];

var x = _.uniq( _.collect( foo, function( x ){
    return JSON.stringify( x );
}));

console.log( x ); // returns [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" } ]
```

Comment: btw, how did you get 4 upvotes? To get at the properties of your result you'd have to revert each array value back into an object. Something like `JSON.parse(x[0]).a` because x isn't an array of objects it's an array of strings. Also, if you add b values to the uniques and invert the order of a/b they are no longer considered unique by your function. (e.g. `"{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":2}" != "{\"b\":2,\"a\":\"1\"}") Maybe im missing something, but shouldn't the result at least be useful? Here is a jsbin to illustrate http://jsbin.com/utoruz/2/edit

Comment: You're right the condition of having the same keys but in different order breaks the implementation.
But I'm unsure why you're only checking the key `a` for each object, when there could be duplicate objects not containing the key `a`.
However, it would make sense if `a` was a unique id.

Comment: When I was answering the question it seemed to me that the focus of the question was to override `(a ==(=) b when a = b = {a:1})`. The point of my answer was the iterator. I tried to answer without worrying about the motive, which could be anything, right? (e.g. maybe they wanted to extract a list of makes, colors from a list of cars in a show. http://jsbin.com/evodub/2/edit) Cheers!

Comment: Also I think it helps us give concise answers when someone asking a question provides motive. This is a race, so I prefer to be first and clarify if necessary. Happy St. Patricks Day.

Comment: Well I just gave another upvote because this answered my question on comparing nested arrays. Was only looking for how to override the `iterator`

Comment: This actually returns `["{"a":"1"}", "{"b":"2"}"]`, the objects will be returned as strings.

Comment: Anyone who has issues with the array of strings can convert them back to objects using: .map( json_str => JSON.parse( json_str ) )

Answer (score 15):

When I have an attribute id, this is my preffered way in underscore:

```
var x = [{i:2}, {i:2, x:42}, {i:4}, {i:3}];
_.chain(x).indexBy("i").values().value();
// > [{i:2, x:42}, {i:4}, {i:3}]
```

Answer (score 12):

Using [underscore unique](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) lib following is working for me, I m making list unique on the based of _id then returning String value of _id:

```
var uniqueEntities = _.uniq(entities, function (item, key, a) {
                                    return item._id.toString();
                                });
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a simple solution, which uses a deep object comparison to check for duplicates (without resorting to converting to JSON, which is inefficient and hacky)

```
var newArr = _.filter(oldArr, function (element, index) {
    // tests if the element has a duplicate in the rest of the array
    for(index += 1; index < oldArr.length; index += 1) {
        if (_.isEqual(element, oldArr[index])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

It filters out all elements if they have a duplicate later in the array - such that the last duplicate element is kept.

The testing for a duplicate uses `_.isEqual` which performs an optimised deep comparison between the two objects see the [underscore isEqual documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) for more info.

**edit: updated to use `_.filter` which is a cleaner approach**

Comment: Doesn't depend on having a predefined unique property? I like it.

Comment: A good solution for a small array of objects but a loop within a loop is expensive compared to providing a uniq id.

Answer (score 10):

The lodash 4.6.1 docs have this as an example for object key equality:

`_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);`

https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith

Answer (score 7):

Try iterator function

For example you can return first element

```
x = [['a',1],['b',2],['a',1]]

_.uniq(x,false,function(i){  

   return i[0]   //'a','b'

})
```

> => [['a',1],['b',2]]

Comment: the seconds argument is actually optional, you can also do `_.uniq(x,function(i){  
   return i[0];
});`

Answer (score 3):

here's my solution (coffeescript) :

```
_.mixin
  deepUniq: (coll) ->
    result = []
    remove_first_el_duplicates = (coll2) ->

      rest = _.rest(coll2)
      first = _.first(coll2)
      result.push first
      equalsFirst = (el) -> _.isEqual(el,first)

      newColl = _.reject rest, equalsFirst

      unless _.isEmpty newColl
        remove_first_el_duplicates newColl

    remove_first_el_duplicates(coll)
    result
```

example:

```
_.deepUniq([ {a:1,b:12}, [ 2, 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 1, 2 ],[ 2, 1, 2, 1 ], {a:1,b:12} ]) 
//=> [ { a: 1, b: 12 }, [ 2, 1, 2, 1 ], [ 1, 2, 1, 2 ] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

with **underscore** i had to use **String()** in the **iteratee** function

```
function isUniq(item) {
    return String(item.user);
}
var myUniqArray = _.uniq(myArray, isUniq);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to solve this simple solution in a straightforward way of writing, with a little bit of a pain of computational expenses... but isn't it a trivial solution with a minimum variable definition, is it?

```
function uniq(ArrayObjects){
  var out = []
  ArrayObjects.map(obj => {
    if(_.every(out, outobj => !_.isEqual(obj, outobj))) out.push(obj)
  })
  return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];
var bar = _.map(_.groupBy(foo, function (f) { 
        return JSON.stringify(f); 
    }), function (gr) { 
        return gr[0]; 
    }
);
```

Lets break this down. First lets group the array items by their stringified value

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(foo, function (f) { 
    return JSON.stringify(f); 
});
```

`grouped` looks like:

```
{
    '{ "a" : "1" }' = [ { "a" : "1" } { "a" : "1" } ],
    '{ "b" : "2" }' = [ { "b" : "2" } ]
}
```

Then lets grab the first element from each group

```
var bar = _.map(grouped, function(gr)
    return gr[0]; 
});
```

`bar` looks like:
`[ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" } ]`

Put it all together:

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];
var bar = _.map(_.groupBy(foo, function (f) { 
        return JSON.stringify(f); 
    }), function (gr) { 
        return gr[0]; 
    }
);
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the code you've provided, try to give some explanation on why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: good call.  Thanks.  Updated with a breakdown of how this works.

Answer (score -5):

You can do it in a shorthand as:

`_.uniq(foo, 'a')`

Comment: your solution does not work for arrays of object, but just for arrays