# Merging two collections using Underscore.JS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Provided I have two collections:

c1 - `[{a:1},{a:2},{a:3}]`

and

c2 - `[{a:1},{a:7},{a:8}]`

what's the fastest way to add unique items from `c2` into `c1` using `Underscore.JS`? The real numbers in collections would be `2K` for `c1` and `500` for `c2`, the operation is performed often, so must be performant!

**Update 1** - I'm only using `Underscore.JS` for a few days, I couldn't find a way to add one collection into another (I can filter `c2` myself) - is that trivial in `Underscore.JS`?

Comment: are the elements in both arrays sorted based on the value of `a`?

Comment: @AlexStack unfortunately not, but I see where you're coming from.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The following will:

- create a new array that contains all the elements of c1 and c2. See [union](http://underscorejs.org/#union).
- from that mix, create a new array that contains only the unique elements. See [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

Note that this would work only if all your objects have the property `a`.

```
_.uniq(_.union(c1, c2), false, function(item, key, a){ return item.a; });
```

You can find other options in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript).

Comment: Right, withouth passing that callback to uniq, the objects will be compared using ===. ({a:1} === {a:1} will be false).

Comment: sound, I just overlooked 'return item.a;', which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
_.uniq(_.union(c1, c2), false, _.property('a'))
```

In detail:

1. `_.union(*arrays)`

   > Computes the union of the passed-in arrays.
2. `_.property(key)` *(since Version 1.6.0)*

   > Returns a function that will itself return the key property of any passed-in object.
3. `_.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iteratee])`

   > Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using `===` to test object equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing `true` for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for `uniq()` function mentions that it runs much faster if the list is sorted. Also using the chained calls can improve readability. So you can do:

```
_.chain(c1).union(c2).sortBy("a").uniq(true, function(item){ return item.a; }).value();
```

Or if you prefer the unchained version (which is 11 characters shorter but less readable):

```
_.uniq(_.sortBy(_.union(c1,c2),"a"),true, function(item){ return item.a; });
```

The documentation and examples for `uniq()` don't make it clear how the callback function works. The algorithm for `uniq()` function calls this function on every element from both lists. If the result of this function is the same, it removes that element (assuming it is duplicated).

`union()` in fact prevents duplicates when called on an array. We can use this fact too:

```
_.map(_.union(_.pluck(c1,"a"),_.pluck(c2,"a")),function (item) {return {a:item};});
```

The above like first converts the list of objects to simple arrays (`pluck()`) then combines them using `union()` and eventually uses `map()` to make a list of objects.

Reference: [uniq()](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a huge number of properties in both objects and this algorithm runs often, it would be better to use core Javascript instead of any library:

```
//adds all new properties from the src to dst. If the property already exists, updates the number in dst. dst and src are objects
function extendNumberSet( dst, src ) {
    var allVals = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < dst.length; i++ ) {
        allVals.push(dst[i].a);
    }
    for ( var i = 0; i < src.length; i++ ) {
        if ( allVals.indexOf( src[i].a ) === -1 ) {
            dst.push( src[i] );
        }
    }
}
```

here is [a JSfiddle to test it](http://jsfiddle.net/9hhhY/3/).