# Compare two arrays of objects in underscorejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have two arrays of objects

```
var arr1 =
    [
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T11:13:09.000Z",
        "email": "concierge@inbound.com",
        "interactionCount": 2
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T21:06:19.000Z",
        "email": "jbi@salesforce.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
        "email": "abc@insightsquared.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "diana@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    }
    ]
```

and

```
var arr2 =
[
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T11:13:09.000Z",
        "email": "concierge@inbound.com",
        "interactionCount": 2
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T21:06:19.000Z",
        "email": "jbi@salesforce.com",
        "interactionCount": 4
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
        "email": "kstachowski@insightsquared.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "hammer@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "life@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 10
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "mike@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 18
    }
]
```

I want to merge these two arrays such that if the email of an object exists in both then diff the `interactionCount` from arr1 with arr2 else return the interactionCount of either arr1 or arr2.

Result will be

```
var result = [
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T11:13:09.000Z",
        "email": "concierge@inbound.com",
        "interactionCount": 0
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T21:06:19.000Z",
        "email": "jbi@salesforce.com",
        "interactionCount": -4
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
        "email": "abc@insightsquared.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "diana@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
        "email": "kstachowski@insightsquared.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "hammer@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 1
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "life@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 10
    },
    {
        "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
        "email": "mike@hubspot.com",
        "interactionCount": 18
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13514962/1702612

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two collections using Underscore.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514121/merging-two-collections-using-underscore-js)

Comment: I have gone through those solutions but they don't do what I need. If you can look the results array, maybe it will be much more clearer as I don't only want to eliminate duplicates but also get a diff of the values wherever the duplicates are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using underscore you can do it like this:

```js
var arr1 = [{
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T11:13:09.000Z",
  "email": "concierge@inbound.com",
  "interactionCount": 2
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T21:06:19.000Z",
  "email": "jbi@salesforce.com",
  "interactionCount": 1
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
  "email": "abc@insightsquared.com",
  "interactionCount": 1
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
  "email": "diana@hubspot.com",
  "interactionCount": 1
}]
var arr2 = [{
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T11:13:09.000Z",
  "email": "concierge@inbound.com",
  "interactionCount": 2
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-31T21:06:19.000Z",
  "email": "jbi@salesforce.com",
  "interactionCount": 4
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-29T11:15:41.000Z",
  "email": "kstachowski@insightsquared.com",
  "interactionCount": 1
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
  "email": "hammer@hubspot.com",
  "interactionCount": 1
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
  "email": "life@hubspot.com",
  "interactionCount": 10
}, {
  "lastInteracted": "2016-03-24T10:02:29.000Z",
  "email": "mike@hubspot.com",
  "interactionCount": 18
}]

var ary = _.chain(arr1.concat(arr2))//use chain
  .groupBy(function(d) {
    return d.email;
  })//grouping by email
  .map(function(d) {
    var last = _.last(d);//take the last in the group
    var k = {
      email: last.email,
      lastInteracted: last.lastInteracted,
      interactionCount: _.reduce(d, function(memo, d1) {
        return memo + d1.interactionCount;//sum up interactionCount
      }, 0)
    };
    return k;
  }).value()

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ary, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L9bhj1hu/2/)

Comment: The Jsfiddle doesn't work. It just prints some functions from the library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update. If try to subtract interactionCounts, Why does it just append '-' to the sum of interactionCounts?

Comment: I think the question is about adding interactionCounts why are you subtracting?

Comment: My bad I completely missed writing the the expected results. I should actually be getting a diff of the two array's interactionCount. I need to track if the interactionCount have increased or decreased over those two arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much @cyril! I really can't believe you actually helped me after I basically changed the requirement. Thanks again :-) :-)