# underscorejs unique does not work

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to use the underscore unique function, but could not get it to work, here is my test code:

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];

_.unique(foo,  function(item, k, v){
    return item.a;
});
console.log(foo);

_.unique(foo, 'a');
console.log(foo);
```

As refered here: [Removing duplicate objects with Underscore for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript), and the test code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/wDvpM/2/, both prints out three objects. I could not figure out the problem, can anybody help? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`uniq` returns a new array. And the function doesn't seem to like it when you omit the second argument.

This works :

```
var foo2 = _.unique(foo, false, function(item, k, v){
    return item.a;
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/syHam/)

Comment: Sorry, the code of my answer was correct but I linked to the wrong fiddle. I fixed that.