# Sorting array of object as strings?

Tags: javascript

I want to find duplicates of objects in an array. I wanna do this by sorting the array and then  comparing the items with each other. How can I compare an object "as a string" that means if there is any difference at all they get sorted accordingly?

It's the sort-function I would like to replace.

```
    var newCart = shoppingCart.sort();

    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < newCart.length - 1; i++) {
        if (newCart[i + 1] == newCart[i]) {
            results.push(newCart[i]);
        }
    }

    this.products = results;
```

Example input:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Skateboard",
        "price": 1299,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/1-t.jpg"
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29000,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },

    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Skateboard",
        "price": 1299,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/1-t.jpg"
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29100,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29000,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },
]
```

Example output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Skateboard",
        "price": 1299,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/1-t.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Skateboard",
        "price": 1299,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/1-t.jpg"
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29000,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },

    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29000,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "A trip to the sun with Erik",
        "price": 29100,
        "currency": "SEK",
        "thumbnail": "/static/img/products/4-t.jpg"
    },
]
```

Note that the last item in the output ends up last, as the price is not the same as the other items with the same ID.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, could you add examples of input and desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a string"? `.toString()` or `JSON.stringify()` or some other serialization?

Comment: How about `JSON.stringify(newCart[i + 1]) == JSON.stringify(newCart[i])` ?

Comment: Updated with example!

Comment: @Sirko that would work, woudl that be a good way to do it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript

Comment: I can't include underscore :/

Comment: Maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: No need to sort here: create a hash using objects `id` and `price` as a hashkey.

Comment: Why not simply sort by id?

Comment: @parchment i want it to be agnostic about the keys in the objects.

Comment: @raina77ow please elaborate! sounds good!

Comment: @parchment, because the items sometimes change it's content and then I need two of them in the shoppning basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify`

```
    function sort(arr) {
        if (arr.length == 0) return [];
        var result = [];
        var v = arr[0];
        result.push(v);
        arr.splice(0,1);;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]) == JSON.stringify(v)) {
                result.push(arr[i]);
                arr.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
            return result.concat(sort(arr));
    }

console.log(JSON.stringify(sort(arr)));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/5u3rncvy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this simple JavaScript **sort** method:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price) } );
```

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5u3rncvy/5/)

Comment: parseFloat, really nice!

Comment: you can apply any property to sort it like id, name, currency etc.

Comment: yes, but I wish to sort it on ANY item changes. not just one.