# Removing duplicates but not saving the copy in array

Tags: arrays, filter, underscore.js

I'm able to remove the duplicates from the JSON given below :

```
var testJSON=[
    {
        "target": "300.0",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2538
        }
    },
    {
        "target": "400.0",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2539
        }
    },
    {
        "target": "300.0",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2538
        }
    },
    {
        "target": "400.0",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2539
        }
    },
    {
        "target": "12.23",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2540
        }
    }
]
```

using underscore _uniq property as:

> _.uniq(testJSON ,'valueObj.id');

which returns only unique property ie.,

```
    {
        "target": "300.0",
        "valueObj": {
            "id": 2538
        }
    }
```

But not displaying other objects .
The result that I'm expecting..

```
[
        {
            "target": "300.0",
            "valueObj": {
                "id": 2538
            }
        },
        {
            "target": "400.0",
            "valueObj": {
                "id": 2539
            }
        },          

        {
            "target": "12.23",
            "valueObj": {
                "id": 2540
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923890/removing-duplicate-objects-with-underscore-for-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this..

```
   var testJSON = _.uniq(testJSON, function (item: any, key, a) {
                     return item.valueObj.id;
                    });
```